# Writing printed output to a file (python)

Tags: python, output

I have a problem with writing my printed output to a file.

My code:

```
list1 = [2,3]
list2 = [4,5]
list3 = [6,7]

for (a, b, c) in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    print a,b,c
```

the output I get is:

```
>>> 
2 4 6
3 5 7
>>>
```

but I have problems with saving this output, I tried:

```
fileName = open('name.txt','w')
for (a, b, c) in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    fileName.write(a,b,c)
```

and various combinations like fileName.write(a+b+c) or (abc), but I am unsuccessful...

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [`write`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_write.htm) method expects a `string`, and your giving it an `int`.

Try using [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [`with`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

```
with open('name.txt','w') as fileName:
    for t in zip(list1, list2, list3):
        fileName.write('{} {} {}'.format(*t))
```

Comment: thanks, this seem to work! I just have to figure out how to add the spaces between the lines, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a format string:

```
fileName.write("%d %d %d" % (a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `with`. Possibly your file handle is not closed, or flushed correctly and so the file is empty.

```
list1 = [2,3]
list2 = [4,5]
list3 = [6,7]

with open('name.txt', 'w') as f:
    for (a, b, c) in zip(list1, list2, list3):
        f.write(a, b, c)
```

You should also note that this will not create new lines at the end of each write. To have the contents of the file be identical to what you printed, you can use the following code (choose one write method):

```
with open('name.txt', 'w') as f:
    for (a, b, c) in zip(list1, list2, list3):
        # using '%s' 
        f.write('%s\n' % ' '.join((a, b, c)))
        # using ''.format()
        f.write('{}\n'.format(' '.join((a, b, c))))
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I get an error here:
f.write(a, b, c)
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Comment: That is because I told you not to do it that way. Please use the second part of my answer.

Comment: I tried the second part as well," f.write('%s\n' % ' '.join(a, b, c))
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (3 given)"

Comment: Sorry, that is my fault, forgot a pair of parenthesis, copy the new version and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `print >> file` syntax:

```
with open('name.txt','w') as f:
    for a, b, c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
        print >> f, a, b, c
```